# Qt how to check if openUrl() is already open ? in windows

Tags: c++, qt, window

in Qt app im opening chm help file using this function :

```
void ToolBar::OpenHelp()
{
   QDesktopService::openUrl(QUrl("my_help_file.chm")) ;
}
```

the problem is when i click it i want it to open only one instance of my_help_file.chm
now i can open how many instances i click the open button.
can if somehow done?

Comment: you can use a urlHandler and check if the URL is still open

Answer (score 1):

There is probably not a good way to achieve what you want with this particular function. You can track whether or not the button has been clicked in your application, but since the application which opens the URL is unknown to you (as it is up to the OS to decide what (if anything) is started), there isn't a good way to know if the user subsequently closes the window.

Answer (score 1):

ok, from this link :
https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/10945

and this class reference :
http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qdesktopservices.html#setUrlHandler

I can suggest a solution for this problem, but I'm not sure if it works.
with UrlHandler you can customize the behavior of openUrl function.

> Well, I think there is no easy way of doing that. At first sight I would say use QProcess to spawn the external process on your own. Take a look at qdesktopservices.cpp on how to do this in a platform-independent manner.

_

> This function provides a way to customize the behavior of openUrl(). If openUrl() is           called with a URL with the specified scheme then the given method on the receiver object is called instead of QDesktopServices launching an external application.

so you can invoke your own process, and handle it.